# MongoDB find() comand

Tags: json, mongodb

this is my first time using mongoDB and database. I have a json file like as image below, I want to get only the name of employee who is UX Designer. So far I know how to get the all detail of her by using `db.collection.find({ "info.job": "UX Designer" })`. Could anyone help me to display only her name
[image of json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CdiU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass fields that you want to be returned as a second parameter to the `find()` method:

```js
db.collection.find({ "info.job": "UX Designer" }, { name: 1 })
```

**Note:** You can pass key/value pairs, where you will specify property names as keys, and values should be `1` if you want these fields to be returned.

Comment: Welcome. Consider also accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped you, so other people that have the same issue would know it worked for you.

Comment: I am also newbie with StackOverflow. They said I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. Please let me know if I could vote you. This answer is correct for me!